# How to mock mongoose schema method in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to test an endpoint which has some middleware 'getFromRequestLean'. I am correctly mocking this but when I add `'.User'`to the end of the require function, it returns me the error listed below. I have to do it this way as it's a schema method. What am I doing wrong? How do I mock this Schema method correctly?

```
const User = require('../models/user').User

router.get('/banner', User.getFromRequestLean, function (request, res) {
})

// model user:

module.exports = {
  User: mongoose.model('User', userSchema),
}
```

This issue is I can mock by doing:

```
const User = require('../models/user').User
const getFromRequestLean = require('../models/user').getFromRequestLean

jest.mock('../models/User', () => ({
  getFromRequestLean: jest.fn(),
  User: jest.fn()
}))

describe('validate banner endpoint', () => {
  getFromRequestLean.mockImplementation((req, res, next) => {
    req.user = { some hash attributes... }
    next()
  })
})
```

I am getting  `Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot on a similar case, I ended up using jest.spyOn:

```js
jest.spyOn(require('../models/user'), 'getFromRequestLean')
  .mockImplementation(() => (req, res, next: any) => next({
    // your code here
  })
)
```